# laravel 4 url rewrite does not work on windows server 2008

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis-7

I have a perfectly working web application developed using Laravel 4.2. This app has been tested 100% and approved by testing team. Now I have uploaded this to Windows Server 2008 R8 running IIS7. I have also set up a domain and the home page works fine.

But there is a problem with url rewrite. For example,

```
http://domain.com  //This works along with css and js loaded properly
```

Now the error part

```
http://domain.com/register             //Doesn't work
http://domain.com/index.php/register   //This works
```

So I tried a method. In the IIS domain for domain.com I imported URL Rules form the .htaccess found in the public folder of Laravel. The import was successful.

Now when I access,

```
http://domain.com            //This works but without CSS and JS
http://domain.com/register   //Now this works but without CSS and JS
```

The .htaccess code I used was

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Why is it that the website works only if `index.php` in between `domain.com` and `register`

Any piece or advise or a working method is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need an IIS-compatible rewrite (URLRewrite) in web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Laravel Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```